# Two Electron windows, hide one from the dock, show the other

Tags: electron

In Electron, I am using `app.dock.hide()` to keep my app out of the dock and out of the (cmd-tab) app-switcher. However, I've now created another window (for preferences) and I'd like this to behave like any other normal window. Is there a way to hide a window from the dock (and hence the app-switcher) on a per-window basis?